# can't follow cite links with org-ref and can't open PDFs with helm-bibtex

Tags: org-ref, helm-bibtex

I'm working with org-ref, helm-bibtex (and org-roam and an org-roam-bibtex if that's relevant).
I've somehow broken my config and would really appreciate any help gathering the pieces...

I can see my various references using helm-bibtex, and I can insert bibliography links with org-ref-insert-link. However, when hitting 'return' with the point on a cite link, instead of a menu with options about the source,  I get a message saying: "wrong type argument stringp, nil", with no reference to the function that throws the error, so I don't even know where to begin investigating... querying what 'return' does in that context only gives the general "org-dwim at point".

Additionally, I can't get helm-bibtex to open the related pdf in emacs (something which used to work for me and broke somehow), but only the related DOI site.

These are the relevant lines from my config (relating to org-ref and helm bibtex) :

```
(require 'org-ref)

(setq
 org-ref-bibli ography-notes "~/google_drive/.notes/.bibliography/bibliography_notes.org"
 org-ref-default-bibliography "~/google_drive/.notes/.bibliography/references.bib"
 org-ref-pdf-directory "~/google_drive/.notes/.bibliography/bibtex_pdf/"
 org-ref-get-pdf-filename-function 'org-ref-get-pdf-filename-helm-bibtex
 org-ref-note-title-format "* TODO %y - %t\n :PROPERTIES:\n  :Custom_ID: %k\n  :NOTER_DOCUMENT: %F\n :ROAM_KEY: cite:%k\n  :AUTHOR: %9a\n  :JOURNAL: %j\n  :YEAR: %y\n  :VOLUME: %v\n  :PAGES: %p\n  :DOI: %D\n  :URL: %U\n :END:\n\n"
 org-ref-notes-directory "~/google_drive/.notes/literature-notes/"
 org-ref-notes-function 'orb-edit-notes)

(setq bibtex-completion-pdf-open-function
  (lambda (fpath)
    (start-process "open" "*open*" "open" fpath)))

(setq
    bibtex-completion-bibliography "~/google_drive/.notes/.bibliography/references.bib"
    bibtex-completion-library-path '( "~/google_drive/.notes/.bibliography/bibtex_pdf/")
    bibtex-completion-notes-path "~/google_drive/.notes/literature-notes/"
    bibtex-completion-pdf-field "File"
    bibtex-completion-find-additional-pdfs t)


(use-package org-roam-bibtex
  :after (org-roam)
  :hook (org-roam-mode . org-roam-bibtex-mode)
  :config
  (setq orb-preformat-keywords
   '("=key=" "title" "url" "file" "author-or-editor" "keywords"))
  (setq orb-templates
        '(("r" "ref" plain (function org-roam-capture--get-point)
           ""
           :file-name "${slug}"
           :head "#+TITLE: ${=key=}: ${title}\n#+ROAM_KEY: ${ref}
- tags ::
- keywords :: ${keywords}
\n* ${title}\n  :PROPERTIES:\n  :Custom_ID: ${=key=}\n  :URL: ${url}\n  :AUTHOR: ${author-or-editor}\n  :NOTER_DOCUMENT: %(orb-process-file-field \"${=key=}\")\n  :NOTER_PAGE: \n  :END:\n\n"

           :unnarrowed t))))
```

I'd appreciate any help, thanks!